# Read One Node of XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml, google-maps, xml-parsing

I have been searching for how to read one node of XML in PHP. The PHP documentation wasn't helpful because I don't understand how to use PHP. All of the tutorials I found weren't useful beacause I only need PHP to read XML(I use CSHTML for Databases and other server-side things). I have working code that can read XML as a tree if it is in a RSS format. I am trying to get the google map geocode api information, from "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=38.7876639,-90.8455276&sensor=false." I only want the very first "Formatted_address" node. My current code is;

```
<?php
$xml=("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=38.7876639,-90.8455276&sensor=false");

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);

//get and output "<result>" elements
$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('result');
for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++)
  {
  $item=$x->result($i)->getElementsByTagName('formatted_address')
  ->result(0)->childNodes->result(0)->nodeValue;

  echo ( $item);
  }
?>
```

However this always returns a 500 error and I don't understand what i am doing wrong. Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `result` to `item`

```
$item = $x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('formatted_address')
          ->item(0)->childNodes->result(0)->nodeValue;
```

As you can see [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/manual/es/class.domnodelist.php) only has one method called `item(int $index)`